# Graphviz decsion tree

Tags: python, tree, graphviz

I want to visualize applied decision tree classifier on my dataset and see how it branches out. Doing several google search, this link came up. I am fine with these codes till this line "f = tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=f)".

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import tree
iris = load_iris()
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
with open("iris.dot", 'w') as f:
...     f = tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=f)
```

My question is after this code how can i visualize the tree? According to the link "http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html", I have to use this code "dot -Tpdf iris.dot -o iris.pdf"  to create a PDF file. I don't understand where should i use this? in the Graphviz’s dot tool? if yes, i get this error "Error: : syntax error in line 1 near 'dot' "

I will be grateful if anybody answer my question.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`dot -Tpdf iris.dot -o iris.pdf` is a command you can use in bash.And you should have Graphviz tools installed.For example,you can install it on ubuntu use command:`sudo apt-get install graphviz`

According to the link "http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html", if we have Python module pydotplus installed, we can generate a PDF file (or any other supported file type) directly in Python:

```
import pydotplus 
dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=None) 
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data) 
graph.write_pdf("iris.pdf")
```

For Shelly's comment, I add the following code, which is the complete code ran on my ipython notebook.

```
import pydotplus 
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import tree
iris = load_iris()
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
with open("iris.dot", 'w') as f:
    f = tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=f)

dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=None) 
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data) 
graph.write_pdf("iris.pdf")
```

Comment: I have installed graphviz. The problem is with this code "dot -Tpdf tree.dot -o tree.pdf" in the cmd. i am getting this error Error: dot: can't open tree.dot

Comment: And when i wanted to do it via pydotplus, i am getting error when it comes to this line  "dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=None) ". The error is like below: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'   which i really don't get why this error is coming up.

Comment: @Shelly 1.`"tree.dot"` should be replaced with the correct dot file path.Make sure you have a tree.dot file right there if you use `"dot -Tpdf tree.dot -o tree.pdf"`. 2.I ran the code of the official document on my ipython notebook, and there was no problem. I have added the complete code to my answer.

Comment: i do have the tree.dot file. Problem is when i use this command "dot -Tpdf tree.dot -o tree.pdf" in cmd it gives me this error "syntax error in line 1 near 'dot' " which i really don't understand how can i solve it or where is my problem?